# How do I recursively search for results in Firestore?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to Node and Firebase.

I'm currently working on a crafting calculator for a game and have the game items stored in Firebase. Some items are composite items, for example:

```
1 Lumber Plank = 5 Logs
```

Based on such requirements, I've structured all the items as a single collection titled as `items` in Firebase.

Log would be persisted as:

```
{
  "type": "basic",
  "name": "log"
}
```

While lumber plank would be:

```
{
  "type": "composite",
  "name": "lumber plank",
  "materials": ["log"],
  "material_values": [5]
}
```

With such a structure, I'm trying to construct a crafting tree by recursively searching through the database. A final structure would look as such:

```
{
    "name": "board",
    "count": 1,
    "materials": [
        {
            "name": "lumber plank",
            "count": 1,
            "materials": [
                {
                    "name": "log",
                    "count": 5,
                    "materials": null
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm having trouble with understanding the callbacks while debugging and this piece of code currently returns `undefined` followed by `log` (I'm assuming this comes from the `console.log` within the `search` function).

```js
async function search(item, result, count) {
    let calcItem = {
        name: item,
        count: count
    };

    db.collection("items")
        .doc(item)
        .get()
        .then(doc => {
            const data = doc.data();
            if (data.type === basic) {
                calcItem.materials = null;
                result.push(calcItem);
                return result;
            } else {
                let materials = data.materials;
                let materialsCount = data.material_values;
                calcItem.materials = [];
                for (let i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {
                    console.log(materials[i]);
                    search(materials[i], calcItem.materials, materialsCount[i]);
                }
            }
        });
}

let item = "lumber plank";

search(item, [], 1).then(result => console.log(result));
```

Would appreciate any pointers/tips here. Thanks

---

Following feedback from Doug,

I've kinda refactored my code based on your comments and I'm seeing some progress.

```js
function recursiveSearch(item, count, result) {
    let calcItem = {
        name: item,
        count: count
    };

    dbSearch(item).then(function (doc) {
        const data = doc.data();
        console.log(data);

        if (data.type === basic) {
            calcItem.materials = null;
            result.push(calcItem);
            return result;
        } else {
            let materials = data.materials;
            let materialsCount = data.material_values;
            calcItem.materials = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < materials.length; i++) {
                recursiveSearch(materials[i], materialsCount[i], calcItem.materials);
            }
        }
    });
}

function dbSearch(item) {
    return Promise.resolve(db.collection("items")
        .doc(item)
        .get()
        .then());
}
```

Log now outputs the search correctly.

```
{
  material_values: [ 5 ],
  materials: [ 'log' ],
  name: 'lumber plank',
  type: 'composite'
}
{
  name: 'log',
  type: 'basic'
}
```

However, if I understand it correctly, if I were to add in this line it's still going to return undefined, am I right?

```
console.log(recursiveSearch("lumber plank", 1, [])
```

If so, how do I actually log out the entire item structure whilst completing all the recursive searches?

Sorry if the question sounds kinda dumb. I primarily come from a Java background and dealing with promises/async/await is entirely new to me

Answer (score 0):

You're not dealing with promises correctly. `search` doesn't actually return a "real" promise, but the caller is expecting it to do so.  Since it's `async`, but doesn't return a value directly, it's actually returning is a promise that always resolves to `undefined`.  It's also apparently intended to be a recursive function, which is making it harder to understand (did you mean to return the promise from the inner call to `search`?).

Minimally, you should start by making search return the promise chain that it establishes:

```
return db.collection("item")...get().then()
```

This will let you receive the value returned by the `then` callback.

I'll also point out that you're started to use async/await syntax, but never committed to using `await` to make this code more easy to read, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: Thanks for getting back, and sorry, I have no idea how to reply to your post with the refactored code and I've added another post.

Comment: hey Doug, following what you said, if I were to edit my original question, should I remove the original post and paste my 2nd solution? or append the follow up question below the original post? Apologies as its my first time posting on Stackoverflow